# What is the strength of ceiling drywall against shim pressure

Tags: drywall, exhaust-fan, bathroom-fixtures

Added a ceiling light/fan fixture to bathroom.

Weight of 9.5lbs.

Instructions called for it to sit flush with drywall on living side. Got close to flush but ran into issue with arms not having appropriate screw holes at the distance which created device sage on arms. Arms are screwed to beams in attic.

I added shims to all four arms between arms and drywall.

Device is secured through arms and shims are under slight pressure to prop up to higher height given the flex in the arms. Really just wondering if drywall will crack or pushout over time.

Obviously 6 months vs 10 years is different.

Without the shims id have to go up unscrew wood screws/cut one or two I stripped, take fan downstairs and put a a few self tappers in the arms to give them more rigidity and then put fan back up. Unwiring and rewiring along the way as well.

Otherwise Ill leave as is.

Could put a couple screws into drywall,  I assume it's nailed up as most of the house is. Will be painting room soon anyway

Comment: A sketch of what you've done would be really helpful.  Sage=sag?